# What is "neg_mean_absolute_error" and where can I find it?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am new to machine learning. I am trying to learn *feature selection* from this [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-for-regression-data/). Here they have a line of code which is given below

```
search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, grid, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=-1, cv=cv)
```

But whenever I try to run this code I get the error

[image]

I cannot find where to import `neg_mean_squared_error` from. I am not sure where I should write the function myself or not. The tutorial isn't clear on this issue.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: Did you read the error message? Try printing `sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys())` and that will show you what values are valid for the `scoring` parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is just a typo.

---

**You need**

```
neg_mean_absolute_error
```

**You typed**

```
neg_mean_absolure_error
```

using an *r* instead of *t*

---

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: Thank you so much. It's so stupid of me. Sorry wasting your time.

Comment: It has happened to me a lot of times. Happy that I could help. consider accepting my answer